# Received unregistered task of type "" in Flask-Celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm trying to integrate celery into my app but I am getting this error saying `Received unregistered task of type "". The message has been ignored and discarded.` My Celery app instance is being created like so:

```
from celery import Celery


def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

My tasks file is like so:

```
from flask import current_app
from .. import celery

from ..models.models import MobileRedemption


@celery.task(name='process_new_redemption')
def task_process_new_redemption(red_id):
    redemption = MobileRedemption.objects(id=red_id).first()

    if redemption:
        assert isinstance(redemption, MobileRedemption)
    print ("Redemption Successful.....!")


@celery.task(name='process_delete_redemption')
def task_delete_redemption(red_id):
    current_app.logger.info("reached here!")
    redemption = MobileRedemption.objects(id=red_id).first()
    print(redemption)
    redemption.delete()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `Celery` construction you should `include` your tasks files:

```
celery = Celery(app.import_name, 
                broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                include=['path.to.tasks'])
```

Comment: @theentertainer did you try?

Comment: whats a sample path like? Getting not a module error

Comment: @PatrickMutuku if you use tasks.py it will be simply `tasks`. If it within tasks/my_task.py it will be `tasks.my_task`  etc